# AWS S3 ZIP file upload is corrupting the archived files

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the below code snippet to upload image through file upload control,zip it using jszip api and then store it in AWS S3.File upload is success and i can see demo.zip in AWS console.However files in demo.zip is getting corrupted and hence unable to unzip it.

I tried my level best to debug,but i did not get any clue on the reason for it.

Any help in correcting my code would be really appreciated.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var uploadservice = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage(), limits: { fileSize: 1000 * 1000 * 12 } }).array("files", 5);
app.post('endpointurl', function (req, res, next) {      
   uploadservice(req, res, function (err) {
       if (err) {           
           console.log("error - " + err)
           res.status(200).end("File upload is failure"); 
       } else { 
           var files = req.files                
            var JSZip = require("jszip");
            var zip = new JSZip();           
            for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++){               
               zip.file('file' + i, files[i].buffer, { binary: true });
            }                
           zip.generateAsync({
               type: "binarystring",
               compression: "DEFLATE",
               mimeType:"application/zip"
           }).then(function (content) {  
               var s3 = new aws.S3();          
               var S3_BUCKET = 'mybucket'
               s3.putObject({
                   ACL: 'private',
                   Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
                   Key: "demo.zip",
                  // serverSideEncryption: 'AES256',
                   Body: content,
                   ContentType: "application/zip"
               }, function (error, response) {
                   if (error) {
                       console.log("error -  " + error)
                       res.status(200).end("File upload failed"); 
                   } else {
                       console.log("success")
                       res.status(200).end("File is uploaded successfully"); 
                   } 
               });
           }) 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry, but I can't comment, so:

What happens if you create the zip file and then open it before moving it to S3?  Perhaps it's the use of `zip.generateAsync({type: "binarystring"`,.... that is causing the corruption.

Comment: Yes.I changed the type to 'nodebuffer' and it started working

Comment: Thanks! My problem wasn't exactly the same, but closing the buffer (zip.close()) before using it though s3fs solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case it gets corrupted after copying into S3.

I've mounted the S3 bucket in an EC2 instance and copying the zip into that particular path. Everything that is copied into that directory gets uploaded into S3.

When I try to unzip after copying it throws "Bad Zip, incorrect headers". I couldn't unzip that. The same zip before uploading works exactly as expected.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32713644)